# Apple does not like the file XIB in xcode project

Tags: xcode, ios8, xib

I've read around the net that Apple does not like the use of multiple XIB files in Xcode6 project. Someone experienced in this thing can 'confirm whether these "rumors" are true or false?

Sorry for the stupid question but I thought to ask here on stackOver saw the large number of experienced iOS developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't care about your internal app structure. This is total nonsense.

Comment: See, I figured that this was nonsense ... Sorry for the stupid question but I do not understand why people have to say things like that just to create more doubts .. So to clarify the way in which you create an app in xcode is not cause for rejection by apple right?